# Trying to use @AppStorage with Singleton, but values don't change until after I reset the app

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to create a singleton class called `Settings` where I have one class dedicated to storing values using `@AppStorage`, so that I can access those values throughout my app. However, for some reason, whenever I make a change, those changes do not update until after I reset the app. Why is this? Is there a better way I can go about fixing this issue?

My code:

```
import SwiftUI

final class Settings: ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared = Settings()
    private init() { }
    
    @AppStorage("message1") var message1: String = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var isOnSettings = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text(Settings.shared.message1)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Image(systemName: "gearshape.fill")
                        .onTapGesture {
                            isOnSettings.toggle()
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isOnSettings) {
            SettingsView()
        }
    }
}

struct SettingsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                TextField("Type", text: Settings.shared.$message1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All `ObservableObject`s need to be wrapped with the appropriate wrapper.

Comment: Use `@AppStorage` for views. Otherwise, use `UserDefaults`.

Comment: @HunterLion Could you clarify what you mean? Should I not be using `@AppStorage` in my class?

Comment: @loremipsum Please clarify how that is related to my question.

Comment: You are using an `ObservableObject` without it being wrapped in one of the appropriate wrappers

Comment: @loremipsum Where exactly am I supposed to be wrapping it? Or should I remove `ObservableObject`?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Comment: @loremipsum Why would I need to do this if the class is a singleton? I am already able to access the class without needing a wrapper. The docs page isn't really helpful here.

Comment: Because SwiftUI requires the wrapper, look into `DynamicProperty` the wrapper works with the `ObservableObject` conformance which listens to `Published` then tells the body it needs to recompute.

Comment: @HunterLion [AppStorage property wrappers now work as expected when contained inside an ObservableObject, causing the system to emit the objectWillChange publisher. (65562845)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-14_5-release-notes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `@AppStorage` when within a struct conforming to `View`. Inside the `ObservableObject` class you should use `UserDefaults`.

Here's an example:

```swift
final class Settings: ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared = Settings()
    private init() { }
    
    @Published var message1: String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "message1") ?? "default value"
}
```

The `string` function will return an optional string, so you'll need to provide a default value in the event that nothing has been saved to UserDefaults yet.

Comment: [AppStorage property wrappers now work as expected when contained inside an ObservableObject, causing the system to emit the objectWillChange publisher. (65562845)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-14_5-release-notes)

Comment: There are several issues with your code

Comment: @loremipsum that's wild since it compiles and works perfectly. Wasn't aware app storage would work now but the code I posted works.

Comment: Issues are deeper than just making code compile. Starting with the statement being incorrect and the unnecessary workaround doesn’t actually save anything to UserDefaults.